# java events and listeners, multiple events in one class

Tags: java, android, events, listener

I am new to android/java and currently am trying to learn custom events and listeners. I currently have this code implemented below that is working successfully. I now would like to add another event to DataRobot. The event will trigger when a certain piece of data is analyzed with the analyzeData function. I was wondering if someone could show me how to implement two events in that one class? I am using this event to trigger an AlarmDialog. So, if there is a better way, let me know.

```
/* SmartApp.java */
public class SmartApp extends Activity 
{
    private ConnectDevice cD = new ConnectDevice();
    private DataRobot dR = new DataRobot();
    private DataBuilder dB = new DataBuilder();
    private DataSender dS = new DataSender();
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.intro);

    cD.addDataReceivedListener(new DataReceivedListener() {
        @Override
        public void dataReceivedReceived(DataReceivedEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            dR.analyzeData(event.getData());
        }
    });
    dR.addDataAnalyzedListener(new DataAnalyzedListener() {
        @Override
        public void dataAnalyzedReceived(DataAnalyzedEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            dB.submitData(event.getData());
        }
    });
    dB.addDataBuilderListener(new DataBuilderListener() {
        @Override
        public void dataBuilderReceived(DataBuilderEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            dS.sendData(event.getData());
        }
    });
      }
}
```

---

```
/* DataRobot.java */
public class DataRobot {
    /* This class is for analyzing the data */
    private List _listeners = new ArrayList();
    private String data;
    public boolean analyzeData(String temp) {
        /* Analyze the data
         * This function analyzes the data, as explained in the OP
         * This function fires the analyzed data event when finished
             * analyzing the data.
         */
        data = temp;
        fireDataAnalyzedEvent(data); // this fires the dataanalyzedevent
        return true; //for now this will always return true
    }

    public synchronized void addDataAnalyzedListener(DataAnalyzedListener listener) {
        _listeners.add(listener);
    }
    public synchronized void removeDataAnalyzedListener(DataAnalyzedListener listener) {
        _listeners.remove(listener);
    }
    private synchronized void fireDataAnalyzedEvent(String temp) {
        DataAnalyzedEvent dRE = new DataAnalyzedEvent(this, temp);
        Iterator listeners = _listeners.iterator();
        while(listeners.hasNext()) {
            ((DataAnalyzedListener)listeners.next()).dataAnalyzedReceived(dRE);
        }
    }
    public interface DataAnalyzedListener {
        public void dataAnalyzedReceived(DataAnalyzedEvent event);
    }
}
```

---

```
/* DataReceivedEvent.java */
public class DataReceivedEvent extends EventObject{
    private String data;
    public DataReceivedEvent(Object source, String temp) {
        super(source);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        data = temp;
    }
    public String getData() {
            // this function is just an accessor function
        return data;
    }
}
```

---

```
/* DataAnalyzedEvent.java */
public class DataAnalyzedEvent extends EventObject{
    private String data;
    public DataAnalyzedEvent(Object source, String temp) {
        super(source);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        data = temp;
    }
    public String getData() {
            // this function is just an accessor function
        return data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How you add a second event depends on if the two events are related. If an object will want to listen to both events, then it is as simple as adding another method to your `DataAnalyzedListener` interface.

The other case is where the events are not related and objects will want to subscribe to one event OR the other. In this case you will want to make two separate interfaces and have two listener lists.

**Other Comments:**

Use a parametrized list instead of the bare type and you won't need to cast the object.
Also you can use a foreach loop instead of grabbing the iterator directly.

```
private List<DataAnalyzedListener> _listeners = new ArrayList<DataAnalyzedListener>();

for (DataAnalyzedListener listener : _listeners) {
  listener.dataAnalyzedReceived(dRE);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Will be attempting now.

Answer (score 3):

I would redesign in Android. Use a service and just register it to receive Intents with certain action types.  Look at it this way:  Intent is your event. Intent Filter is your Intent mapping, and event manager is by calling context.startActivity(Intent) or by broadcasting the Intent (pub/sub eventing) thats the Android way.